# Accepting potentially dangerous characters and preventing Stored XSS

Tags: security, xss

I have some fields in a web application whose requirement is to accept any characters and store them in a database. They’re later retrieved and displayed a few ways including JQuery binding, an MVVM framework, etc.

What is the correct way to accept and handle this data? Do I encode the data at the server side before it is stored or store it in its original format? Do I analyze each rendering method to see how they safely handle data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It's the latter, XSS is an output encoding problem.

You can store any user input in your database, that by itself is not vulnerable. Of course if you can, you should do input validation, but sometimes because of the nature of the data you expect in normal operation, you can't really validate some inputs. That's not a huge problem, XSS in general cannot be stopped by input validation anyway.

One argument against storing encoded values in the database is that it's a separation of concerns thing. There are several different encodings (HTML, Javascript, URL, XML, etc.) and the component that receives the data may (and should) have nothing to do with the one that later renders it. The other argument against it is related to this one, when storing the data, you don't want to know how it will be rendered, so you can't choose the right encoding. Also searching or ordering will be much more difficult with encoded data. So you should just store it as received.

To prevent XSS, you have to carefully implement output encoding according to the context (plain html, javascript, json, xml, whatever) when writing such data to some kind of an output. Note that this is not at all straightforward, for example in an HTML page, not just a script block creates a javascript context, but for example event attributes (onclick, onmouseover, etc) also do, as does the href for an < a > tag, if the variable is the first character of the href value (see `javascript:alert(1)`).

But the bottom line is, you always have to find the right encoding method, and encode all of your variables upon writing them to the output.

MVVM is a somewhat special case. Most client-side templates have methods to write a variable encoded or raw, also client-side data binding usually provides facilities to bind a variable as a parsed html node or just as text. Obviously, you should opt for text, html may be vulnerable to XSS if user input is involved. This practically means things like using the `text:` binding in Knockout instead of `html:`, or using jQuery's `.text()` method instead of `.html()`.

In these cases, data is usually downloaded in an AJAX request as JSON, where it still doesn't need to be encoded, because you still don't necessarily know where you will use it, and you may still want to search/sort on the client (but for this to not be vulnerable, you need to send it with an `application/json` content type, and not `text/html`). But it's just data, and JSON is just a data format. Of course it needs to be encoded to JSON though, but standard object serializers do that for you. If you want to generate JSON into the page though (say to initialize an SPA), you need to HTML encode values in the JSON object - it's better and easier to get this data with AJAX.